# Android client cannot connect to server using socket

Tags: android, sockets, server

I write a simple app with the function of connecting to the server. However, I encounter some problems that I cannot connect to the server.Here is the code of the client.

```
 public void extablishconnection(){
    mThreadPool.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                // 创建Socket对象 & 指定服务端的IP 及 端口号
                socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 9999);
                // 判断客户端和服务器是否连接成功
                boolean m=socket.isConnected();
                System.out.println(socket.isConnected());
                if(m) {
                    Log.d("Connect", "It is true");
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.d("Connect","It is false");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Here is the code of the server:

```
    import sys
import socket
serversocket = socket.socket(
    socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host=socket.gethostname()
serveraddress=('127.0.0.1',9999)
serversocket.bind(serveraddress)
serversocket.listen(5)

clientsocket,addr=serversocket.accept()
serversocket.close()
print("connection address: %s" % str(addr))
msg='Welcome！'+ "\r\n"
clientsocket.send(msg.encode('utf-8'))
clientsocket.close()
```

Here is the logcat of the android:

```
    2021-06-30 16:48:51.517 17799-10867/? W/HiAdKit.HttpUrlConnectionCaller:  http execute encounter UnknownHostException - http code: -1
2021-06-30 16:48:51.518 17799-10867/? I/HiAdKit.HttpUrlConnectionCaller:  close connection
2021-06-30 16:48:51.591 11167-11242/com.example.magickeyboard D/Connect: It is false
2021-06-30 16:48:52.054 1706-2313/? D/HwConnectivityServiceEx: set 1000 NULL value false
2021-06-30 16:48:52.630 1706-2273/? D/HwConnectivityManagerImpl: startappqoednscollection action =1timer =1000
2021-06-30 16:48:52.840 1706-2228/? D/HwConnectivityManagerImpl: startappqoednscollection action =0timer =1000
2021-06-30 16:48:53.661 11250-11310/com.example.magickeyboard D/Connect: It is false
2021-06-30 16:48:54.513 1706-3541/? D/HwConnectivityManagerImpl: startappqoednscollection action =1timer =1000
2021-06-30 16:48:54.713 1706-3541/? D/HwConnectivityManagerImpl: startappqoednscollection action =0timer =1000
2021-06-30 16:48:56.413 1706-3541/? D/HwConnectivityManagerImpl: startappqoednscollection action =1timer =1000
2021-06-30 16:48:56.611 1706-2494/? D/HwConnectivityService: return the background wifi network info for system manager.
2021-06-30 16:48:56.840 17663-11093/? I/fwkit_ReleaseNetConnect: remove evict message
2021-06-30 16:48:56.840 17663-11093/? I/fwkit_ReleaseNetConnect: send evict message
2021-06-30 16:48:56.846 1706-6970/? D/HwConnectivityService: return the background wifi network info for system manager.
2021-06-30 16:49:01.844 17663-21907/? I/fwkit_ReleaseNetConnect: screenOff = true
2021-06-30 16:49:01.844 17663-21907/? I/fwkit_ReleaseNetConnect: ScreenOff close all connect
2021-06-30 16:49:20.774 17799-10876/? I/HiAdKit.HttpUrlConnectionCaller:  createConnection: https://******/app******
2021-06-30 16:49:20.779 17799-10876/? W/HiAdKit.HttpUrlConnectionCaller:  http execute encounter UnknownHostException - http code: -1
2021-06-30 16:49:20.779 17799-10876/? I/HiAdKit.HttpUrlConnectionCaller:  close connection
2021-06-30 16:49:45.330 17799-10854/? I/HiAdKit.HttpUrlConnectionCaller:  createConnection: https://******/exS******
2021-06-30 16:49:45.335 17799-10854/? W/HiAdKit.HttpUrlConnectionCaller:  http execute encounter UnknownHostException - http code: -1
2021-06-30 16:49:45.336 17799-10854/? I/HiAdKit.HttpUrlConnectionCaller:  close connection
```

Comment: Where is your server running? As you use 127.0.0.1 it should run on the same Android device as your client is running on.

Comment: Do not bind your server.